# Can I obtain the ClickOnce published Product Name from inside the application?

Tags: c#, installation, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Publish Name that is different from the assembly name.  For discussion purposes, it is "App 6.0".  I set it in the Properties for my project.  Is there any way to get this value from inside the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in *[ClickOnce Run at Startup](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/02/24/clickonce-run-at-startup/)*. Essentially, you use InPlaceHostingManager to get the ClickOnce manifest and read it. It bugs me that it is an asynchronous method, but this is the only thing that has worked thus far. Simplifications are much appreciated. See the webpage for a description of DeploymentDescription.

```
var inPlaceHostingManager = new InPlaceHostingManager(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation, false);
inPlaceHostingManager.GetManifestCompleted += ((sender, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        var deploymentDescription = new DeploymentDescription(e.DeploymentManifest);
        string productName = deploymentDescription.Product;
        ***DoSomethingToYour(productName);***

        // - use this later -
        //var commandBuilder = new StartMenuCommandBuilder(deploymentDescription);
        //string startMenuCommand = commandBuilder.Command;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
});
```

Comment: `InPlaceHostingManager` is at `System.Deployment.dll`. Where is `DeploymentDescription` located?

Comment: @DaviFiamenghi the class you are looking for is in a comment on the linked post. I have edited the answer to include it, waiting for review. if you follow the link and search the page for the class you will find it.

Answer (score 5):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll`, then run this:

```
if (null != AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext)
{
    DeployManifest manifest;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext.DeploymentManifestBytes))
    {
        manifest = (DeployManifest)ManifestReader.ReadManifest("Deployment", stream, true);
    }
    // manifest.Product has the name you want
}
else
{
   // not deployed
}
```

The DeployManifest can also provide other useful info from your manifest, like Publisher or SupportUrl.

Comment: What are the version requirements, if any, for this to work (e.g. for .NET Framework and/or Visual Studio)?

Comment: This should be the answer because it is complete and without broken links (as the currently accepted answer is)

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationDeployment.UpdatedApplicationFullName Property

Comment: This doesn't quite give the right answer.  I'm looking for the ProductName that is entered into the Clickonce Publish options.  I found a solution which uses the manifest, but it isn't the most elegant.